# kendo-ui exportPdf and exportExcel stop

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that can potentially contain several thousands of rows. What I'm wanting to do is have the user confirm that they actually want to continue with the export if the row count exceeds 5,000.

So in the grid's DataBound event I'm using jQuery.off method to unbind the link's click event and then I'm using jQuery.on('click') afterwards to display a confirm that the user wants to export those rows.

The problem that I'm running into is that the confirmation modal will display, but the grid still exports when the button is clicked (and before a response is given in the confirmation modal).

I've tried using the preventDefault method in the jQuery.on('click') event, but this doesn't prevent the export from taking place either.

To make a long story short. How can I conditionally prevent the kendo grid from exporting?

Comment: Did you tried `return false` in the event ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and it has to do with how Kendo wires up the button events. I had to call `stopPropagation`. So what I did was setup a boolean variable outside of the button's clicks event equal to if the row count was greater than or equal to 5,000. Then if the boolean variable was true I used `stopPropogation` and displayed a confirmation modal. If the user clicked yes then I set the boolean variable to false and reinvoked the click event. Outside of the condition, I set the boolean variable back to the result of the row count used initially.